# How to programmatically add referrer for Google Maps API key?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to build a multi domain site platform where, basically like Wordpress.com, where user can sign up for new site and they can post contents under different domain with other users. At first it will be under a subdomain of the product website (e.g. the product's domain is `www.example.com`, and domain for the user1 is `user1.example.com`). But user can choose to use her own domain (e.g. user using `user1.example.com` can use `www.my-domain-example.com`).

In the sites, I'm planning to show a Google Map. As we know when we want to get browser API key, there will be this dialog to add the referring sites (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iTUi.png).

In the dialog above, I can easily use `*.example.com/*` for the regular sub-sites. But should a user choose to use her own domain, how do I update the referring site programmatically? Is there an API for that?

Comment: They need to tell you their domain name or they need to register for their own key.

Comment: Let's say they submit their domain name in the registration form in my site. How to update the referrer without manually open the Google API console and open the dialog mentioned above?

Comment: You can't access the developer console programmatically.

Comment: This is really disappointing. We've got a large enough number of domains (running on a CMS built on app engine) that it's impractical to manage the referrer restrictions by hand. We've also signs of unauthorised use of our maps api keys in the past. Our CMS is designed for people who aren't tech savvy, so asking them to get their own API key is unrealistic.

Comment: There may be an update to this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57859494/1880657