# Need to exceed 1200 referrer url limit in Google Javascript API

Tags: google-api, google-api-javascript-client

So my colleague ran into this error while attempting to add http referrers to our javascript maps api key. Our app needs to be able to hit the api from our client domains, and there are well over 1200 of them. Has anyone hit this limit, if so, how have you surpassed it?
[image]

Comment: Would it be possible split up the referrers using multiple keys?  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40017418/referrer-limit-per-google-maps-api-key).

Comment: Yes, that'd be possible. That's one of the solutions on the table, in fact. The one I'm pursuing right now is wrapping the map in an iframe pointed to a page on a domain we own on the same site.